# Showing content in frame interferes with animation on the page

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-runtime

I ran into a little problem while writing Windows 8 application on C#+xaml. My app has one main page, which is divided in two parts – ListView as a navigation panel on the left, and Frame on the right. All of that looks and works a bit like [PC Settings panel](http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Windows-8-PC-Settings-Sync.png). But there is one difference – when page into frame has enough content and it’s scrollable, I perform animation of collapsing navigation panel to icons-only state (when in full width it has text and icons).

So, here is the problem. Let’s say I’m on the first page and panel is collapsed. Then I go to the second page, and I've got to return to full-width state of panel. But since I’m doing it at the same time as showing content in the frame, there is a little freeze of animation, and it's becoming really noticeable when GridView has got a lot of items. So animation freezes on a half way, then GridView render all items images, and then it continue.

Only way to fix this problem I come up with, is to do navigation after animation completed. It’s doesn’t look very pretty, so I go on a blank page first, perform animation, and then go on target page. But this solution still feels wrong, and there still some problems with animation after resume from suspending.

So, is there any way to ensure that rendering of GridView will not interfere with my animation?
Thank you, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set NavigationCacheMode on the pages to Required and navigate through all the pages to preload them while hiding the Frame using the Opacity property, but that will be slow the first time you do it. Try to limit the number of bitmap pixels you need to decode and render on each page too. If all else fails - see if the Preload() method of the AlternativeFrame control from WinRT XAML Toolkit might be of help.

Comment: Preloading all the pages hardly a solution, since I've got six of them, and some with quite amount of items. I certainly will do my best to decrease number and size of pictures, but the freeze will still be there, even a small one. Not to mention that it would be good to know right solution for this kind of problem for the future.
I was thinking of looking at third-party tools myself, and probably now is the good time to learn some of them.
So thank you for specific advice - I hear of WinRT XAML Toolkit quite a lot, might be a good place to start.